# ARM64 linux early boot stage hard hang post mmu enable - Check update

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, arm64, u-boot, mmu

I am trying to boot arm64 linux( custom kernel config built from current git master as of 09/23/21 ) on a cortex A53, emulated on a FPGA platform. The available mem I have is 2GB( 0x0 - 0x80000000 ). I used u-boot as the bootloader to pass uImage to a load point( and same entry point): 0x10000000.

Through an external jtag debugger I can see that the execution is in **head.S** (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm64/kernel/head.S ) running the function,(**__enable_mmu**). The moment the TTBR registers are set and the SCTLR register to enable mmu are executed, the system goes into a hard hang. I immediately lose the ability to track the program counter. I am assuming that the mmu got enabled, but I am not sure what went wrong.( no early prints till this point ).

**My doubt:**

- I see in head.S that linux does the bare minimum in terms of setting up page table entries before enabling mmu. I would assume that it's standard. Is there anything that could go wrong at this step. If the page tables didn't get set up correctly, how do I verify & fix this. I am relatively new to mmu related stuff.

***Update***:

- After loads of trial&error, disabling dcache somehow made it go past the hard hang. I changed the parameters passed to sctlr( enabled mmu, disabled caching ), the boot proceeded without any **issues*** . My question is, *why did this work*. This is definitely indicative of a deeper issue. Does the dcache flush/invalidation not happen properly? Is the timing of cache operations out of sync?

The boot does go and crash down the line during attaching of drivers but that's a different issue.

Any insight would be helpful. Cheers!

Comment: How well have you tested this prototype board?  Or are you booting Linux to exercise/test its functionality?  Did you try running the memory tests available in U-Boot?

Comment: MMU startup code is fragile, but it sounds like you haven't made any code changes there. 
Is your JTAG reliable on a known-good A53-based dev board?

Comment: @sawdust I edited my question rn to reflect this too. It actually is a single core A-53 with minimum peripherals emulated on a FPGA platform. It is well tested in the sense that I have run ARM's bare metal code that has mmu tests and such in qemu and on FPGA and have not seen this issue then.

Comment: @JoeKul , the jtag is reliable. It's a Lauterbach debugger.

Comment: Are you in a situation where you can accurately time (like on a logic analyzer) the interval between enabling SCTLR and the system "hang"?  If it is the *next* instruction that is likely a straightforward logic error.  But if it is a semi-random interval of a few microseconds, it is probably in reaction to an interrupt service routine trying to run, most likely the timer or a network interface.

Comment: @wallyk, unfortunately I have no means at the moment to accurately time the interval. I did check if it could be an ISR or any other interface, it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question to resolve this matter. This is a very specific corner case and it had to do with how the HW was configured for the FPGA platform. The HW design had clock-gating implemented which was messing up the read cycles between cache and memory, leading to the hard hang.